# WCF Callback for UDP

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, udp

Как в WCF, получая и отправляя данные по UDP использовать Callback?

```
 IScreenCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IScreenCallback>();
 callback.GetCoonectedPc("iumag");
```

Данный код работает только по TCP, если я меняю Binding на UDP, то он не может отправить callback клиенту. Выдает Exception

> Дополнительные сведения: Указанное сообщение невозможно отправить, так
>   как неизвестно место назначения. Этот транспорт требует, чтобы для
>   свойств Message.Headers.To или Message.Properties.Via исходящих
>   сообщений было задано допустимое значение.

Как работать с Callback по UDP?

Comment: а чем вас TCP не устроил? Он отлично работает в дуплексе, даже отвалившихся клиентов без шаманства ловит, в отличие от HttpDual. UDP хорош для мультикаста, а для дуплекса лучше TCP, да и надежней на сколько это возможно.

Comment: @rdorn, передавать скриншоты с периодичностью 500мс(а то и больше) будет, наверное, лучше UDP. А клиент должен принимать за 500 мс, таких 15 скриншотов с разных серверов

Comment: Эм... прикольно, а вы уверены, что сеть,в которой будет ваш клиент, сможет обеспечить такую скорость в принципе? скриншот ни разу не маленькая картинка с учетом современных мониторов. Лучше опишите, что вы пытаетесь сделать

Comment: @rdorn, Передаваться будет не все изображение, а только изменившейся часть и когда клиент будет запрашивать 15 скриншотов, то еще будет картинка сжиматься и там получает каждые 500 мс(можно даже больше сделать). Так же можно получать одно изображение в полноэкранном режиме. Делаю подобие NetOp School. Сейчас это все реализовано на TCP, но нужно все перенести на UDP.